# Git Rebase on a Specific Remote, Branch, and Commit

Tags: git, rebase, git-remote

The situation is:

I've got a local git repo with no set remotes. I want to add a remote for a specific branch, which a believe I can do like this:

`git remote add New_Remote -t -f {New_Remote_Branch} {Repo}`

I then want to rebase my local git repo not just to the HEAD of `New_Remote_Branch` but to a specific commit of it. I've read the docs and I've seen the `--onto` option but I'm a bit confused about how to target it to a specific remote and and commit. I've had trouble testing this concept and finding the syntax. I believe I'm looking for something like:

(from the local repo directory)

`git rebase New_Remote/New_Remote_Branch --onto {New_Remote_Branch_Specific_Commit_id}`

Comment: Git doesn't care that commit is on a remote branch or on a local branch or not even on any branch: For `{New_Remote_Branch_Specific_Commit_id}`, you can just provide the relevant commit id and you should be allset. Make sure you `git remote update` first to make sure you have local copies of any remote refs.

Comment: ...and as always, if you're not sure you're doing the right thing, you can always operate on a copy of your repository until you get things working the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

The full syntax of `git rebase` is:

```
git rebase --onto $new_upstream $old_upstream $branch_to_rebase
```

It will take all commits between old_upstream and branch_to_rebase and recreate them on top of new_upstream. In the end, the "branch_to_rebase" ref will point to the newest of the recreated commits.

All three arguments can be a branch, tag, or commit. The last one should usually be a branch, otherwise you end up in *detached HEAD* state (but it's easy to recover). The first two arguments only need to resolve to a commit.

So in your case, your command will look something like:

```
git rebase --onto $specific_commit_id master your_branch
```

(assuming that you want to copy all commits on your branch that were created since master)